# jQuery each() doesn't work using OOP approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my situation in javascript:

```
EA = {
    DOMElement: $('#example img'),
    photos: '',
    ...

    countSelected: function(){
        var len = 0;
        var id = '';

        EA.DOMElement.each(function(index){
            id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            EA.photos += id + ",";
        });

        len = EA.photos.length;
        return len;
    },   
}
```

The function countSelected return 0 but if I use this solution all works fine:

```
    countSelected: function(){
        var len = 0;
        var id = '';

        $('#example img').each(function(index){
            id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            EA.photos += id + ",";
        });

        len = EA.photos.length;
        return len;
    },
```

In my opinion the problem is in selector: $(this). 
Do you know any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You do know you are just getting the length of a string, and not the number of elements? And the second parameter of `each(index, element)` is a refference to the element ?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZTRm/ It iterates through the img tags in the selector stored in the `EA.DOMElement` property. Must be related to something else. Mind you, I had to make up the HTML as it wasn't in the post.

Comment: Not a solution but note you could use `$(this).data('id');`

Answer (score 2):

The question is, when did you initialize the namespace? If you did so before the DOM was fully ready, and/or if images were added later under that `#example` element, then the jQuery reference is stale.

You have a couple of options. One is to initialize it later; another is to use the jQuery call every time (like in your second code snippet); another is to create a function in the namespace that will invoke the jQuery constructor whenever you need it (which at least allows you to reduce selector duplication).

Comment: I initialize the namespace in this way: $(document).ready(function(){ EA.init(); });

Comment: Yes, but you create the namespace itself sooner than that (i.e., you run `EA = {/* stuff */}` before document ready. Thus the jQuery call will not work.

Comment: I agree with @PlatinumAzure . The code is working fine. you must be initializing before you have any `#example img`s

Comment: @MarkDesign They are right, since you are setting a property to the value of `$('#example img')` before the `#example img` element even exists, you are basically setting DOMElement's value to an empty selector, which is why the code is not working. You must set the value of DOMElement within a `$(document).ready()` handler.